# How to salvage this quick proof of the exponential sum law in Banach algebras

Tags: analysis, exponential-function, banach-algebras

From the power series definition of the exponential function in the real or complex numbers you can quickly prove the sum rule by considering the function
$$
f(x) = \exp(a + b - x) \exp(x),
$$
proving that f'(x) = 0, then using that to show that f(0) = f(b), which gives you $\exp(a + b) = \exp(a) \exp(b)$.

I have been interested in extending this argument to arbitrary Banach algebras.  I was talking with someone else about it, and our idea was to use the function
$$
f(t) = \exp((1 - t)(A + B) + tA) \exp(tB)
$$
where $t$ is a real number, and, assuming that $AB = BA$, the previous argument seems like it works.  However, in looking at it further I realized that applying the chain rule would require figuring out what the derivative in an arbitrary Banach algebra would be, and I can't think of any definition of the derivative that I know of that would work.  So, my question basically is, is there a way to salvage this proof?  Is there some kind of derivative that will work here?  If not, is there some other way to make it work?  I know that the traditional way of proving this involves fiddling with series, but I was wanting to see if I could make this argument work.